# Java, JFrame: getWidth() returns 0

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
setExtendedState(getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
setResizable(false);
setUndecorated(true);
System.out.println("--------> "+getContentPane().getWidth()); //----> 0 why is this happening?
```

I'm trying to determine the size of a JFrame. I've searched on google and checked the documentation and I still don't know why it won't work
It works fine on about any other control I try it on

EDIT:
frame.getWidth() works when called outside of the class (that extends JFrame)
still, if I replace

```
System.out.println("--------> "+getContentPane().getWidth());
```

with

```
System.out.println("--------> "+this.getWidth());
```

getWidth will still return 0

EDIT2:
I need the frame's size before setting it visible and stuff. I need to add other controls to the frame and their coordinates and size depend on the frame's size.

Comment: everything depends how you layed the container, if is there definitions for `setSize()` or `setBounds()`, then any reall `Dimension` returns only visible `Container`, otherwise if `JComponents` returns its `PreferedSize` to the `Container`, then you can get this `Dimension` anywhere you want

Comment: @madflame991, To your second edit, this is not possible, nor does it make sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason why you got 0 is because you didn't call any of the pack(), setSize(int, int) or setSize(Dimension). This is only when calling one of these method that the layout of your frame will be computed.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
frame.setExtendedState(getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.pack(); // Important line!!! 
frame.setVisible(true);
System.out.println("--------> "+getContentPane().getWidth());
```

Comment: I need the width before I'm finished adding controls

Comment: I run the test and it seems that you cannot get the frame width is it's not visible but I realized that if your frame is always JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH, then the frame width is equal to the screen width, which you can get by `Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();int screenWidth = tk.getScreenSize().width;`

Comment: Thank you! getScreenSize is not what I was looking for but it pretty much solves my problem

Answer (score 10):

You haven't *realized* (i.e. `setVisible(true)`) the `JFrame` yet. And therefore, it has no size since it hasn't laid out its components.

Comment: 1+. `pack()` will also render the JFrame (I believe).

Comment: I tried calling it after making it visible and it still returned 0

Comment: @madflame991, This might be a stupid question, but did you add any components to the `JFrame` prior to making it visible? And as @Hovercraft mentioned, perhaps invoking `pack()` is the better option, since this will force the container to layout its components and then make itself visible.

Comment: inc. @Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggestion +1

Comment: *"`pack()` is the better option,"* Agree. *"..since this will force the container to layout its components"* Agree "*and then make itself visible."* No it doesn't.  `pack()` is usually called just before `setVisible(true)`, but does not itself affect the visibility.

Comment: @Andrew, You're completely right. I forgot to remove my comment! :D